# Trying to Iterate through a list and getting the error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

**Description of what I am trying to do**

I have a list (called `rf1` in my code) that is size 2977x30 that I am trying to iterate over. The values in this list are either a string representing parts of a polynomial or a constant integer. I also have a DataFrame of zeros (called `zeros`) that is the same size but contains only 0 in each spot. One thing that is different about `zeros` is that the column headings correspond with the minimum and maximum powers that are found in the polymonials (-13 to 16).

I am trying to search through each of the locations in my list `rf1` by row and column to see if a particular substring is found within that cell. If it is, I add the cell to my list `zeros` in the column that corresponds to the power of the polynomial. If not, nothing happens.

Here is what `rf1` looks like and how it was created:

```
rf1 =               0           1           2            3  ... 26 27 28 29
      0             x        x**3        -x^4            0  ...  0  0  0  0
      1       x**(-2)    -x**(-1)           1           -x  ...  0  0  0  0
      2          x**2        x**4       -x**5         x**6  ...  0  0  0  0
      3             x       -x**2      2*x**3        -x**4  ...  0  0  0  0
      4       x**(-2)    -x**(-1)           2         -2*x  ...  0  0  0  0
      ...         ...         ...         ...          ...  ... .. .. .. ..
      2972   -x**(-3)   4*x**(-2)  -7*x**(-1)           11  ...  0  0  0  0
      2973  2*x**(-4)  -7*x**(-3)  14*x**(-2)  -20*x**(-1)  ...  0  0  0  0
      2974   -x**(-2)   5*x**(-1)         -11         18*x  ...  0  0  0  0
      2975         -x      6*x**2    -10*x**3      16*x**4  ...  0  0  0  0
      2976       x**5        x**7        x**8      -4*x**9  ...  0  0  0  0

rf = pd.read_csv('sheet3.csv', names=name2)
print(rf)
rf1 = rf.copy()
rf1 = rf1.values.tolist()
```

Here is what `zeros` looks like and how it was created:

```
zeros =       -13  -12  -11  -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  ...  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
        0       0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        1       0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2       0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        3       0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        4       0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ... .. ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
        2972    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2973    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2974    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2975    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2976    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0  ...  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
zeros = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(rf1)), columns=name)
```

**What I have tried**

When I was doing some trials before fully implementing my code, I was able to get it to work. This is what I did in the trial runs:

```
# Value at rf1[1][1] is -x**(-1)

if "**(-13)" in rf1[1][1]:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
if "**(-1)" in rf1[1][1]:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```

This returned

```
False
True
```

Once I realize that this method seemed to work, I implemented a line to add the code to my array of zeros:

```
if "**(-13)" in rf1[1][1]:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
if "**3" in rf1[1][1]:
  zeros.loc[[1],['-12']] = rf1[1][1]  # This corresponds to the wrong spot, 
                                      # but just putting it here to see if it worked.
else:
  print(False)
```

This turned my DataFrame of zeros into:

```
zeros =       -13       -12  -11  -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  ...  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
        0       0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        1       0  -x**(-1)    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2       0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        3       0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        4       0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        ...   ...       ...  ...  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ... ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
        2972    0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2973    0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2974    0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2975    0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        2976    0         0    0    0   0   0   0   0  ...  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I know that this method works, so implemented it on the full spectrum. (I will abbreviate the code because it is egregious and you can get the point from a few lines:

```
for i in range(0,2978):
  for j in range(0,31):
    if "**(-13)" in rf1[i][j]:
      zeros.loc[[i],['-13']] = rf1[i][j]
    if "**(-12)" in rf1[i][j]:
      zeros.loc[[i],['-12']] = rf1[i][j]
    ...
    if "**15" in rf1[i][j]:
      zeros.loc[[i],['15']] = rf1[i][j]
    if "**16" in rf1[i][j]:
      zeros.loc[[i],['16']] = rf1[i][j]
```

But when I do this, I get the error:

```
<ipython-input-54-751e9bee77da> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0,2978):
      2   for j in range(0,31):
----> 3     if "**(-13)" in rf1[i][j]:
      4       zeros.loc[[i],['-13']] = rf1[i][j]
      5     if "**(-12)" in rf1[i][j]:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

I have absolutely no idea what I am going wrong. I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is a smaller, more full version of my data:

```
rf1:
         0         1       2      3      4      5     6  7  8
0        x      x**3    -x^4      0      0      0     0  0  0
1  x**(-2)  -x**(-1)       1     -x   x**2      0     0  0  0
2     x**2      x**4   -x**5   x**6  -x**7      0     0  0  0
3        x     -x**2  2*x**3  -x**4   x**5  -x**6     0  0  0
4  x**(-2)  -x**(-1)       2   -2*x   x**2  -x**3  x**4  0  0

zeros:
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: The size of this data is too large, to the point that it is not easily portable. Please reduce the scope of this question to the minimum number of rows and columns necessary to reproduce the issue. Include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information.

Comment: It looks like your cells are sometimes numbers, sometimes strings. The most expedient solution would be `if "**(-13)" in str(rf1[i][j]):`, which would convert the cell to a string before looking for `**(-13)` as a substring.

Answer (score 0):

This is because value of `rf1[i][j]` is a integer and you can not use `in` operator with an integer.

You can verify this

```py
print('a' in 1)
```

Output

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```